# Why ssh require a password?

Tags: ssh

I have two computers, on one debian on another ubuntu. I want to connect to the computer with debian(**server**) and the ubuntu computer(**client**), using ssh.

**server** :

```
root@R2CPU:/# service ssh start
root@R2CPU:/# ifconfig
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.16.8.169  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 172.16.8.255
        ether 00:1f:f2:00:00:00  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 43109  bytes 27547659 (26.2 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 2  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 5268  bytes 300768 (293.7 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        loop  txqueuelen 1  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 855  bytes 81193 (79.2 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 855  bytes 81193 (79.2 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

root@R2CPU:/#
```

configuration file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`  :

```
#       $OpenBSD: sshd_config,v 1.100 2016/08/15 12:32:04 naddy Exp $

# This is the sshd server system-wide configuration file.  See
# sshd_config(5) for more information.

# This sshd was compiled with PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

# The strategy used for options in the default sshd_config shipped with
# OpenSSH is to specify options with their default value where
# possible, but leave them commented.  Uncommented options override the
# default value.

#Port 22
#AddressFamily any
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::

#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

# Ciphers and keying
#RekeyLimit default none

# Logging
#SyslogFacility AUTH
#LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:

#LoginGraceTime 2m
PermitRootLogin no
#StrictModes yes
#MaxAuthTries 6
#MaxSessions 10

#PubkeyAuthentication yes

# Expect .ssh/authorized_keys2 to be disregarded by default in future.
#AuthorizedKeysFile     .ssh/authorized_keys .ssh/authorized_keys2

#AuthorizedPrincipalsFile none

#AuthorizedKeysCommand none
#AuthorizedKeysCommandUser nobody

# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
#HostbasedAuthentication no
# Change to yes if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for# HostbasedAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts no
# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
#IgnoreRhosts yes

# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
#PasswordAuthentication yes
#PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
# some PAM modules and threads)
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes
#GSSAPIStrictAcceptorCheck yes
#GSSAPIKeyExchange no

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
UsePAM yes

#AllowAgentForwarding yes
#AllowTcpForwarding yes
#GatewayPorts no
X11Forwarding yes
#X11DisplayOffset 10
#X11UseLocalhost yes
#PermitTTY yes
PrintMotd no
#PrintLastLog yes
#TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no
#UsePrivilegeSeparation sandbox
#PermitUserEnvironment no
#Compression delayed
#ClientAliveInterval 0
#ClientAliveCountMax 3
#UseDNS no
#PidFile /var/run/sshd.pid
#MaxStartups 10:30:100
#PermitTunnel no
#ChrootDirectory none
#VersionAddendum none

# no default banner path
#Banner none

# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem       sftp    /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#       X11Forwarding no
#       AllowTcpForwarding no
#       PermitTTY no
#       ForceCommand cvs server

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes
#KerberosGetAFSToken no

# GSSAPI options
```

**client**:

comp@comp0:~$ nmap -Pn -p22 172.16.8.169

```
Starting Nmap 7.60 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2019-10-02 13:58 MSK
Nmap scan report for 172.16.8.169
Host is up (0.0015s latency).

PORT   STATE SERVICE
22/tcp open  ssh

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.05 seconds
comp@comp0:~$ ssh 172.16.8.169
comp@172.16.8.169's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
comp@172.16.8.169's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
comp@172.16.8.169's password: 
comp@172.16.8.169: Permission denied (publickey,password).
comp@comp0:~$ ssh 172.16.8.169 -i root
Warning: Identity file root not accessible: No such file or directory.
comp@172.16.8.169's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
comp@172.16.8.169's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
comp@172.16.8.169's password: 
comp@172.16.8.169: Permission denied (publickey,password).
comp@comp0:~$
```

**where to find the password ???** Why does it require a password ?? Despite the fact that in the settings `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`: `PermitRootLogin no`.

Comment: The password is whatever password you would normally use to login as `comp` on the host. The `PermitRootLogin` setting does not come into play since you are not trying to log into the root account. I'm not turning this into an answer because I'm slightly confused by the question. Why would a password _not_ be required? You are not using any SSH keys, as far as I can see, so logging in using the ordinary login credentials would be the only way to log in with SSH.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PermitRootLogin no - means You do not want root user to come over SSH, which is best practice.

password for any local user can be changed using

```
passwd username
```

example: 
On destination server machine 
create user

```
useradd testssh
```

change password

```
passwd testssh
```

from source machine connect to destination. use password You created

```
ssh testssh@172.16.8.169
```

One more thing, option #PubkeyAuthentication yes means PublickeyAuthentication is enabled by default, and this is the main way to use ssh without password. You can use public/private key authentication.

Comment: Comment at the beginning of the `sshd_config` file: "The strategy used for options in the default sshd_config shipped with OpenSSH is to specify options with their default value where possible, but leave them commented." So `#PubkeyAuthentication yes` means public key authentication is **enabled by default** and the configuration file is not currently changing that, so it is still **enabled**. This is also indicated by the login response `Permission denied (publickey,password).`